# IRC Ident issue

Tags: c#, tcpclient, irc, ident

This is what I'm getting:

```
:portlane.esper.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:portlane.esper.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:portlane.esper.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname
:portlane.esper.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response
```

I know I need to listen and write on tcp: 113, but I don't know what method I should use, or what I need to do.. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace Bot
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ConnectToServer(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Server = "irc.esper.net";
            int Port = 5555;
            string Nick = Nickname.Text;
            string Channel = ChannelName.Text;
            TcpClient IRCClient = new TcpClient(Server, Port);
            NetworkStream Stream = IRCClient.GetStream();
            StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(Stream);
            Writer.NewLine = "\n\r";
            Writer.AutoFlush = true;
            Writer.WriteLine("/USER Bot Bot Bot :Bot");
            Writer.WriteLine("/nick " + Nick);
            Writer.WriteLine("/join " + Channel);
            Writer.WriteLine("Hello.");
            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Reader.ReadLine());
            }
            Reader.Close();
            Writer.Close();
            Stream.Close();
            IRCClient.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("End of stream.");
        }
    }
}
```

If any of you wouldn't mind, a response with an example would be appreciated.

Thanks,

~ abcd3fg

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send ident responses (this is usually not needed and is usually difficult because you need to have a port accessible from Internet), you need to make a separate TCP server listening on port 113 and implementing the ident protocol. You can use `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` as a base for the server (note that you either will need to deal with blocking etc. or make it a separate executable). For the protocol itself you may look directly in `RFC 1413` (the protocol is line-based and quite simple, especially of you don't need to implement it properly and just return a static fake response). Still, I'm not sure that you need an ident server and even if you do that you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: It appears to be needed, because the server isn't accepting my IRC connection. What other possible things could be causing this?

Comment: @abcd3fg depends, but it's worth noting that commands you send to the server are totally wrong, you need to read about the IRC protocol.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you dont send /commands, you have to send proper IRC commands. Read the RFC about it. Clients do /commands but what it sends to the actual server is different. IE: "NICK newnick",  not "/nick NEWNICK"